# how to split at a new line in an array with JS?

Tags: javascript

So i have this line of code

```
 function getTokens(rawString) {
        return rawString.toLowerCase().split(/[ .!?",:;-]+/).filter(Boolean).sort();
    }
```

which splits each word in an input text into an array.

but the problem is that i can't split words from a new line, for example when i   something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gycM.jpg)

it gives out this [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWdy2.jpg) which combines the word "help" and "folks" in a one word.

How can i adjust the upper line of code (in a simple way) so that it splits the words on each new

line?

Comment: For better reponse I would suggest inlining your output. Most of us won't bother going other places for more information on your question. Make it as easy as possible for others :)

Comment: In general it is a bad idea to make screenshots of things that can be copied as text, such as... text. source code. error messages. stack traces.

Comment: i see, ill keep that in mind :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split on `/[\s.!?",:;-]+/`.

`\s` contains all whitespace characters, newline included (also tab and others).